# Express Js + Mongoose + Joins

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have two collections. size and items. size is referred in items, I need to add size title while query items

Size collection

```
size:[{
_id: 123
title: S
},{
_id: 456
title:M
}]
```

Item collection

```
items:[{
title: item1,
    sizes:[{
     _id: object I'd
     sizeid: 123
     Price: 100
     },{
       _id: object I'd
       sizeid: 456,
       Price: 150
      }]
   }]
```

How to perform the join to get below output

```
items:[{
title: item1,
    sizes:[{
     _id: object I'd
     sizeid: 123
     size: S ----> from size collection
     Price: 100
     },{
       _id: object I'd
       sizeid: 456,
       size: M -----;> from size collection
       Price: 150
      }]
   }]
```

Comment: `.populate()` ?

Comment: Yes I have used populate and posted the workaround in below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to design a property sizes of Items Schema as a array of ObjectIDs which will refer to Sizes Schema.

```js
const ItemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    ...
    sizes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sizes' }]
  }
);
```

Then when you need to get size just doing

```js
const result = await Items.findOne(_id: itemId).populate('sizes');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added as virtual field. I'm beginner in MERN stack.

```
itemSchema.virtual("sizemaster", {
  ref: "size",
  localField: "sizes.sizeId",
  foreignField: "_id",
});

itemSchema.virtual("itemsize").get(function (this: any) {
  const sizemaster = this.sizemaster;
  const itemsize = this.sizes.map(
    (s: {
      _id: any;
      sizeId: any;
      purchaseprice: any;
      mrp: any;
      salesprice: any;
      availablequantity: any;
    }) => {
      const sizeIndex = sizemaster.findIndex(
        (sm: { _id: { equals: (arg0: any) => any } }) => sm._id.equals(s.sizeId)
      );
      if (sizeIndex !== -1) {
        let itemsize = {
          itemsizeId: s._id,
          sizeId: s.sizeId,
          sizeTitle: sizemaster[sizeIndex].title,
          mrp: s.mrp,
          salesprice: s.salesprice,
          availablequantity: s.availablequantity,
        };

        return itemsize;
      }
    }
  );
  return itemsize;
});
```